# htaccess 3 parameters rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this problem is asked before, but i don't find anything

i try to pass 3 variable in htaccess the url change normaly but i cant't get the third variable

this is my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ index.php?r=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+) index.php?r=$1&s=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+) index.php?r=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+) index.php?r=$1&id=$2&s=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Not related to your stated problem, but note that RewriteCond only applies to the _next_ RewriteRule, so the "if not exists" check currently only applies to the first rule. The easy you've spaced out the lines makes it look like you intended your conditions to apply to all three rules, but it doesn't tell Apache that.

Comment: The problem only in the third variable so the first three rule correct , ?? i don't know about htaccess a lot so anything i get i will use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+) index.php?r=$1&id=$2 [L]
> RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+) index.php?r=$1&id=$2&s=$3 [L]
> ```

These 2 rules conflict. A URL of the form `/abc/123/def` is also matched by the first rule, so the second rule is never processed.

You could either:

- Include an end-of-string anchor (`$`) on the first rule pattern, so that it only matches `/abc/123` and not `/abc/123/def`. For example:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?r=$1&id=$2 [L]
  ```
- OR, reverse these two directives, so the rule for 3 parameters takes priority:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+) index.php?r=$1&id=$2&s=$3 [L]
  RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+) index.php?r=$1&id=$2 [L]
  ```

You should probably include end-of-string anchors on all your patterns, otherwise, they are likely to match too much. eg. `/abc/123/def/for/bar/baz.jpg` is matched by the 3rd and 4th rule without an end-of-string anchor. If you add end-of-string anchors then the filesystem conditions could probably be removed altogether.

As @IMSoP noted in comments, those two conditions (ie. `RewriteCond` directives) only apply to the first `RewriteRule` that follows. The first rule is unlikely to match a real file anyway, so the conditions aren't really doing anything currently.

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Comment: it work when i add the end-of-string (`$`) ... thanks a lot